# Equal digit sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $s(a)$ be the sum of decimal digits of a number $a$. Is it known that for any $a\ne b$ exist $n$ such that $s(na)\ne s(nb)$?

Comment: Maybe the following properties of the function $s$ could be useful; $s(a+b) \le s(a) + s(b)$ and $s(a)s(b) \le s(a)s(b)$.

Comment: And of course, the sum of digits of $a$ is divisible by $3$ (or $9$) if and only if $a$ itself is divisible by $3$ (or $9$). So $n = 1$ suffices if exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of $3$. 

Comment: Counterexample: $a=1$, $b=10$.  But it's probably true (and may be reasonably easy) that the only counterexamples are those for which $b/a$ is a power of $10$.

Comment: If the greater of $a$ and $b$ is coprime to $10$ then there exists $n$ such that $na = 10^c - 1$ for some $c$, and then clearly $s(na)>s(nb)$.  [This argument would already prove the guess if the base were prime.]  It may be possible to expand on this trick to deal with even numbers and multiples of $5$.

Comment: [that is, we may assume without loss of generality $a>b$; if $\gcd(a,10)=1$ then there exists $n$ etc.]

Comment: For what it's worth, one can assume that at least one of $a,b$ is coprime to 10: if $a$ and $b$ are related as in the question, and $a$ is even, then $5a$ and $5b$ are also related as in the question, and hence so are $a/2$ and $5b$. Arguing like this one can reduce to the case where one of $a,b$ is coprime to 10 and the other is not a multiple of 10, and then one has to prove $a=b$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, but if we replace condition $a\ne b$ to $a/b\ne 10^k$ for all integers $k$.

Lemma: $s(9n)=9s(n)$ iff decimal digits of $n$ are only 0's and 1's. Else $s(9n)<9s(n)$.

Call two numbers equivalent, if their ratio is a power of 10 (with integer exponent).

Consider numbers 1,11,111,... Two of them are congruent modulo a, hence their diffrence 11...100..0 equals $ka$ for some natural $k$. Replace pair $(a,b)$ to $(ka,kb)$ and then replace new $a$ (old $ka$) to equivalent number of the form 11...1, totally $m$ ones. Also, divide $b$ to maximal possible power of 10.

Now $s(9a)=9s(a)$, hence the same holds for $b$, hence by lemma $b$ also has only 1's and 0's in its decimal representation and the number of ones equals $m$. In particular, $b>a$ and last digit of $b$ equals 1. Now choose $N$ such that $Nb=11\dots 1$, then $Na < Nb$ and due to $s(Na)=s(Nb)$, $Na$ has a digit different from 0 and 1. Then by lemma $s(9Na)<9s(Na)$, while $s(9Nb)=9s(Nb)$. A contradiction.

I know this as an old problem by Sergey Berlov, by the way. First time I saw it in 1997 in Sochi on the event for high school students I have participated in:)

Comment: I don't quite follow the "hence $b$ also has only 1's and 0's" conclusion.  What about $a=11$ and $b=2$?  

Comment: we must have $s(9b)=9s(b)$, for $b=2$ it is not so. 

Comment: You can shorten your proof by Elkies' trick: choose $N$ such that $Nb=99\dots9$, then $Nb>Na$, so $s(Nb)>s(Na)$. A contradiction.

Comment: Oh sorry!  My stupid mistake!

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to emphasize that $s(n+m)\leq s(n)+s(m)$ with equality iff there is no digit carry when adding $n$ and $m$, cf. Barry's comment and Woett's very first comment.

Comment: Very nice arguments. But there is a little gap in the proof. You assume that $b$ is not divisible by $10$, but you use stronger assumption: $(b,10)=1$. I think that we should add some more arguments in this proof. 
1) We can start with $a_0$ such that $(a_0,10)=1$ (otherwise we can multiply $a$ by $2^k$ or $5^l$ removing $0$'s). 
2) In this case $k$ ($a=11...1=ka_0$) will be coprime with $10$ as well. It means that $b=kb_0$ has no $0$'s at the end.

Comment: @Alexey: There is no gap, just more details should be added. $s(9a)=9s(a)$ implies $s(9b)=9s(b)$, which means that there is no carry when multiplying $b$ by $9$ in the decimal system. So $b$ only has digits $0$ and $1$. The digits $0$ at the end can be deleted, so $b$ ends with $1$, hence it is coprime with $10$. Maybe you meant the same. I certainly agree that the proof is written too densely. 

Comment: That all gives only that $a=2^kC$, $b=5^mC$. This much can be achieved in many ways. The devilish casework is after that and I don't know a decent proof (not that I thought of it too hard though) 

Comment: @fedja: Fedor Petrov's proof is OK, there is no casework to do. First of all, as Kevin Buzzard pointed out in a comment to the original post, we can assume that $a$ is coprime to $10$. Then $n\cdot 9a=10^c-1$ for some integer $n>0$, so replacing $a$ by $na$ (resp. $b$ by $nb$) brings us to the situation that Fedor Petrov starts with. Then $s(9a)=9s(a)$, hence $s(9b)=9s(b)$, which means that there is no carry when multiplying $b$ by $9$ in the decimal system. So $b$ only has digits $0$ and $1$. The digits $0$ at the end can be deleted, so $b$ ends with $1$, hence it is coprime to $10$.

Comment: @fedja: I continue. Now $s(a)=s(b)$ gives $b>a$, so the argument can be finished by Elkies' trick. We choose $N$ such that $Nb=10^d-1$, then $Nb>Na$, so $s(Nb)>s(Na)$, a contradiction.

Comment: @all: I tried to make the exposition complete and self-contained.

Comment: Ah, all right. Sometimes I get totally confused with simple but not explicitly mentioned steps :). OK, agreeing and voting up then...

Comment: I like this version better. Still, you can simplify it by Elkies' trick: $9Na<9Nb$ implies directly that $s(9Na)<s(9Nb)$, no need to invoke the Lemma again.