# Sums of digits again

Tags: nt.number-theory

To complete my answer to [this question,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94704/the-digit-sums-again-how-far-they-can-be-equal) one needs to prove the following conjecture that seems to be true:

- For every two natural numbers $a \lt b$, $a,b\not\equiv 0\mod 10$, there exists $n\lt b$ such that the sums of decimal digits of $na, nb$ are different.

Note that we cannot claim $n\le a$ because for $a=10^k+1, b=10^{k+1}+1$, the smallest such $n$ is $10^k+9$ (for every $k \ge 1$).

**Update**  It looks like if $n=n(a,b)$ exceeds $b/10$, then $a$ and $b$ (if big enough) must have a very specific form: all but two digits are  0's or all but 2 digits are 9's. If that is true, my conjecture will be true as well. In fact even if $n(a,b)\ge \sqrt{b}$, then $a$ and $b$ look very similar.